# TwitterKit didEncounterError (withMessage Invalid parameter not satisfying- error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter, twitter-fabric

I've seen this question asked once before on StackOverFlow but there was not a satisfactory answer so I'm asking once more.

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (session)
        {
            setting.isConnectTwitter = YES;
        } else
        {
            setting.isConnectTwitter = NO;
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
```

when I run this and try logging in through Twitter, it seems to work, but after a few seconds, the error "TwitterKit didEncounterError (withMessage Invalid parameter not satisfying- error)" appears.

I followed the Twitter login tutorial quite literally and I'm very frustrated by the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. I was told to ignore it since its not causing any crashes. I think what ends up happening is that when we set up the TwitterKit it automatically assumes you are using Crashlytics so then it goes into info.plist and tries to find the information for the Crashlytics and it can't find it so then it prints out an error. But your app doesn't crash.